$L^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^{p,\infty}(\Omega)$ if $\Omega$ is compact
Given a compact set $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$, I am wondering if $L^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in the weak $L^p$ space $L^{p,\infty}(\Omega)$ with $1< p<\infty$ (see here the definition).
I would like to know if the proof is as simple as using that $L^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$ along with the fact that $L^p(\Omega)\subset L^{p,\infty}(\Omega)\subset L^q(\Omega)$ for any $q \leq p$.

Actually, the closure of $L^\infty$ in $L^{p,\infty}$ is
$$
L^{p,\infty}_0:=\left\{ f:\lim_{t\to\infty}t^p\mu\{x:\lvert f(x)\rvert>t\}=0  \right\}.
$$
Indeed, if $f$ belongs to the closure of $L^\infty$ in $L^{p,\infty}$, for each $N$, there exists a function $f_N\in L^\infty$ such that
$\sup_{t>0}t^p\mu\{x:\lvert f(x)-f_N(x)\rvert>t\}<N^{-1}$. Then
$$
t^p\mu\{x:\lvert f(x)\rvert>t\}\leqslant t^p\mu\{x:\lvert f(x)-f_N(x)\rvert>t/2\}+t^p\mu\{x:\lvert f_N(x)\rvert>t/2\}\leqslant \frac{2^p}N+t^p\mu\{x:\lvert f_N(x)\rvert>t/2\}
$$
and since $f_N$ is bounded,
$$
\limsup_{t\to\infty}t^p\mu\{x:\lvert f(x)\rvert>t\}\leqslant \frac{2^p}N
$$
hence $f$ belongs to $L_0^{p,\infty}$.
Conversely, if $f$ belongs to $L_0^{p,\infty}$, then we can show that $f_N\colon x\mapsto f(x)\mathbf{1}_{\lvert f(x)\rvert\leqslant N}$ approximates $f$ with respect to the semi-norm
$$
\lVert g\rVert_{p,\infty}=\left(\sup_{t>0}t^p\mu\{x:\lvert g(x)\rvert>t\}\right)^{1/p}, 
$$
since
$$
\lVert f-f_N\rVert_{p,\infty}^p=\sup_{t>0}t^p\mu\{x:\lvert f(x)\rvert>\max\{t,N\}\}\leqslant \sup_{t\geqslant N}t^p\mu\{x:\lvert f(x)\rvert>t\}.
$$

Were you already typing your excellent answer when I wrote mine, or is this a reaction post? :) Just curious.

I was typing this answer, then I saw yours.

This density is not true.
Let $\Omega=(0,+1)$. Let $p\in (0,\infty)$ and define
$$
f(x) = x^{-\frac1p}.
$$
Then
$$
\mu(\{x:\ |f(x)| > t\} ) = t^{-p}
$$
for $t\ge1$, so that $\|f\|_{L^{p,\infty}} = 1$.
Let now $g\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ with $N:=\|g\|_{L^\infty}$.
Let $t>0$. Then
$$
\mu(\{x:\ |f(x)-g(x)| > t\} ) \ge 
\mu(\{x:\ |f(x)| > t+N \} ) = (t+N)^{-p},
$$
so that
$$
t^p \mu(\{x:\ |f(x)-g(x)| > t\} ) \ge t^p (t-N)^{-p} \to 1
$$
for $t\to\infty$.
